# Using read() and write() in place of scanf() and printf() in C

Tags: c, shell, command-line, include, fork

I want to use `read()` and `write()` methods for reading from and writing to console instead of the original `scanf()` and `printf()`, as the first ones has system calls support using signals.

I have to make a mini Unix shell, which forks into children when performing a command. Here is my initial try for testing the reading and writing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define COMMAND_LENGTH 1024
#define NUM_TOKENS (COMMAND_LENGTH / 2 + 1)

void read_command(char *buff, char *tokens[], _Bool *in_background) {
    // to be implemented later
}

void createStr(char **str) {
    if (*str != NULL) {
        free(*str);
        *str = NULL;
    }
    *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * COMMAND_LENGTH);
}

void delStr(char** str) {
    if (*str != NULL) {
        free(*str);
        *str = NULL;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char input_buffer[COMMAND_LENGTH];
    char *tokens[NUM_TOKENS];
    char *inp = NULL;
    while (true) {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "> ", strlen("> "));

        createStr(&inp);
        read(STDIN_FILENO, input_buffer, sizeof(char) * COMMAND_LENGTH);
        strcpy(inp, input_buffer);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, inp, strlen(inp));
        _Bool in_background = false;
        read_command(inp, tokens, &in_background);
    }
    delStr(&inp);
    return 0;
}
```

My output for sample inputs are not the desired ones. Here is a sample output:

```
> Peterson
Peterson
��> Makr  
Makr
son
��> Mark
Mark
son
��> Jon
Jon
son
��>
```

I don't know what is going on. Like why the special characters are showing up, as well as having parts of my last input in my new input. I need help in this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `read()` doesn't add a null terminator to the input, it returns the number of characters that it read. String functions like `strcpy()` and `strlen()` expect it to have a null terminator.

Comment: There's also no guarantee that `read()` will return exactly one line. It may return a part of a line, or multiple lines. You need to search for the newlines to see where each input line ends.

Comment: Additionally, the `read()` function is generally ill-suited for interactive input.

Comment: Hello @Barmar, the problem is that the reading buffer still has some text left over, because I also printed the length (using strlen()) of the input buffer, and it shows a wrong strlen() (a correct one for the outputs shown, but not the actual needed length).

Comment: @JohnBollinger is there any way I can simulate scanf in read()??

Comment: The buffer allocated by `malloc()` may have anything in it, it doesn't zero it first. If you want it initialized, use `calloc()`.

Comment: You can't call `strlen` on the buffer you just got back from `read`.  You have to use `read`'s return value (which you're currently ignoring.)

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_. And don't cast trhe result of `malloc` & friends in C! Also **always** check the result of functions for errors!

Comment: Don't use `read` and `write` (POSIX) on `stdin` and `stdout` unless you have some really compelling reason *not* to use the `<stdio.h>` functions.  You probably want `fgets` for input and `fprintf` for output.

Comment: @SteveSummit what does read returns??

Comment: `read()` returns the number of bytes read or a -1 on error.  See `man 3 read` on linux for details....

Comment: @falhumai, if you insist on using `read()` to perform the actual I/O, and you want whitespace-delimited input such as `scanf()` can provide for you, then you need to implement the needed parsing as a layer on top of `read()`.  As Barmar already explained, there is no reason to expect the parsing to be synchronized with the low-level reads. It would be a lot simpler to use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: I don't see the point of `createStr(&inp); read(STDIN_FILENO, input_buffer, COMMAND_LENGTH); strcpy(inp, input_buffer);`. (I removed `sizeof(char)*` because it's always 1.) What's the point of reading into one buffer and then copying into another one? You could just read directly into `inp`. Or you could parse the data you read from `input_buffer`. In any case, everything you malloc() needs to be free()d.

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with using `read` here -- *if you know how to use it*.  But, falhumai, you have to know how to use it.  You have to know that it deals with a counted buffer of raw characters, *not* with a null-terminated string.  You have to know that you have to know the number of characters it reads.  You ought to be able to guess that `read`'s return value will be that number. It has to be obvious to you that, having called `read` and discarded the return value, you don't know the count and can't use the buffer properly (much less call `strlen` on it).

Comment: Ok thank you all for the help.

Comment: Your easiest way forward will be to say `r = read(`...`)`, then `if(r < 0)` exit on read error, then `if(r == 0)` exit on EOF, then set `input_buffer[r] = '\0';`, then treat `input_buffer` as the string you thought you had all along. *But* if you do that you're going to have to declare `char input_buffer[COMMAND_LENGTH+1];` to leave room for the `\0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must store the return value of `read`, verify that `read` completed and null terminate the string before passing it to `strcpy`.  `read` can indeed be interrupted by a signal and must be restarted in this case.  `read` can also return a partial line, you should keep reading and concatenating into the command buffer, carefully reallocating the buffer if needed, until you receive either an end of file of the character `'\n'`.